# SQL Select From Where Different columns must be equal

Tags: sql-server

I need to join 2 tables where the primary key is the Reference.

UAP = Production Unity

First table has the UAP consumption rate per week

```
AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H
```

Second table has the UAP available stock, however, in each table, the UAP have different names but they are the same.

```
AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M
```

For example, on first table, I have UAP1, and on second table, this is called M1, so basically here is the association

```
Table1       Table2

UAP1    -    M1
UAP2    -    M2
UAP3    -    M3
UAP4    -    M4
UAP5    -    M5
UAP6    -    M6
UAPP    -    Protos
EXT     -    EXTR
```

here is the query so far

```
SELECT 
    Reference, 
    UAP, 
    CAST(W01 AS Float) AS W01, 
    CAST(W02 AS Float) AS W02, 
    CAST(W01 / 5 AS Float) AS DailyW01, 
    CAST(W02 / 5 AS Float) AS DailyW02, 
    CAST(Stock as Float) AS Stock 
FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        A.RH6001 as Reference, 
        A.RH6002 as UAP, 
        A.RH6030 as W01, 
        A.RH6031 as W02,
        S.LLBLT1 AS Stock
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H AS A
    LEFT JOIN  AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M AS S
    ON A.RH6001 = S.LLPPN 
    WHERE (A.RH6001 Not Like ''FS%'')
    AND S.LLBLT1 <> 0')
```

I only need to somehow group the records by reference and show the correct stock per UAP that it belongs to. This would be easy if the names were the same but they are different.

Is there a way to handle this without making a lot of IF clauses?

Here are the separated queries

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
    'SELECT 
        IC130M.LLPPN AS Referencia, 
        IC130M.LLSTLC AS UAP, 
        IC130M.LLBLT1 AS Stock
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.IC130M IC130M
    WHERE IC130M.LLSTLC IN (''M1'',''M2'',''M3'',''M4'',''M5'',''M6'',''EXTR'',''PROTOS'') 
    AND IC130M.LLBLT1 <> 0 
    ORDER BY IC130M.LLSTLC ASC, IC130M.LLBLT1 DESC')
```

this returns this

[image]

and here the consumption per week table

```
    SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MACPAC, 
        'SELECT TRP060H.RH6001 as Referencia, 
                TRP060H.RH6002 as UAP, 
                TRP060H.RH6030 as W01, 
                TRP060H.RH6031 as W02
    FROM AUTO.D805DATPOR.TRP060H TRP060H
    WHERE (TRP060H.RH6001 Not Like ''FS%'') ')
```

[image]

Comment: Why you wouldn't have a foreign key to link the tables seems like poor design.

Comment: I know but this is a linked server, i cannot manage these, I only extract data

Comment: You could make a table which stores these relationships and join on it as a junction table between the two, that would help cut down on all the if clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this is to simply add a relationship table.   In other words, create a new permanent table from this, and use it to JOIN the two tables you have:

```
UAP1    -    M1
UAP2    -    M2
UAP3    -    M3
UAP4    -    M4
UAP5    -    M5
UAP6    -    M6
UAPP    -    Protos
EXT     -    EXTR
```

Comment: So you are saying i have to create this table locally so i can associate the remote tables with it?

Comment: Unless you're able to create it on the remote server, then yes.

Comment: It's probably best solution since i already have a table with the UAP names, just need to add a 2nd column. Thanks